# JavaScript Inheritance prototypical

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Why do we need to set prototype object for inheritance when we can directly inherit  parent properties if we call the constructor method using this in each child function?

```
function Employee() {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}

function Manager() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.reports = [];
}
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
```

We can use inheritence even if we don't set prototype of `Manager` as `Employee`.

Comment: Try `new Manager() instanceof Employee` without it, or try putting stuff on `Employee`’s prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Usually prototypes are used to put functions/methods on them, not properties, because with properties you'll have a single property value shared between all object instances. Also, you may not need to set prototype for inheritance if you add methods inside a constructor. For example:

```
function Employee(name) {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
  this.reportName = function() {return this.name};
}

function Manager(name) {
  Employee.call(this, name);
  this.reports = [];
}

var manager = new Manager('Peter');
manager.reportName(); // Peter
```

However, adding methods/function inside object's constructor is inefficient, since every time a constructor is called an instance of a function is created. So usually, all methods, not properties, are allocated on prototype like this:

```
function Employee(name) {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}

Employee.prototype.reportName = function() {return this.name};
```

Now, in this case, simply calling a constructor won't be enough:

```
function Manager(name) {
  Employee.call(this, name);
  this.reports = [];
}

var manager = new Manager('Peter');
manager.reportName(); // throws an error
```

You need to set a prototype:

```
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype)

var manager = new Manager('Peter');
manager.reportName(); // 'Peter'
```